# Como criar uma view que liste os domains no Firebird 2.5?

Tags: firebird

Alguém sabe como montar um SQL que liste os "domains" em um database do Firebird 2.5? Grato.

Answer (score 2):

Peço desculpas e espero que levem em conta que tenho pouca experiência com firebird.

O SQL correto é:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW "Domains"( "Name" )
AS
select distinct
                        RDB$Field_Name
from
                        RDB$Fields as Fields
where
      substring (Fields.RDB$Field_Name from  1 for 4) not in ('IBE$', 'MON$', 'RDB$')
order by
                 Fields.RDB$Field_Name
```

No entanto, considero um tanto confuso que na tabela RDB$Fields, o campo RDB$Field_Name englobe tanto os "Fields" propriamente ditos e os "Domains".